# Export CSV using jQuery AJAX call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have some code to export the results of a search to a CSV file:

```
$("#exportButton").click(function () {

    var url = "/Stuff/ExportSearchResults";
    var searchInput = readInput();

    $.post(url, searchInput, function (data) {
        // This is where I'm clueless.
        // I'm getting data back but not sure how to make the
        // browser show a prompt to download the file.
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

At the server side (ASP.NET MVC 4) there's this:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult ExportSearchResults(SearchInput model)
{
    string csv = GenerateCsv(model);
    return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "Export.csv");
}
```

So the good thing is that I'm getting data back in the console. I'm just not sure how I would make the browser show a prompt to download a file.

Comment: Short answer, you should't use ajax for this kind of task, but a direct call instead...

Comment: doing this successfully cross browser could be painful - maybe [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) could help

Comment: window.location.href = '/Stuff/ExportSearchResults'; try like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here for this question we can go with comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349021/sreepathy-sp

At Client side

```
$("#exportButton").click(function () {

       var url = "/Stuff/ExportSearchResults";
       var searchInput = readInput();

       window.location.href = '/Stuff/ExportSearchResults?searchInput='+searchInput ;
});
```

At server side

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult ExportSearchResults(string model)
{
    string csv = GenerateCsv(model);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv));
    return File(stream , "text/csv", "Export.csv");
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need to use a POST though. We can't have the parameters showing up in the url.

Comment: @Aetherix : can you please give clarity for your readInput();. If its a data retrieved from database, we can recreate the post model in our method ExportSearchResults .